# Recieving a EOF Panic error

Tags: go

I'm trying to decode a json I get. Here's an example json I get:

```
{"response":"1","number":"1234","id":nil}
```

Here's my struct:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
Response string  `json:"response"`
Number     string  `json:"number"`
ID         interface{}     `json:"id"`
}
```

I use the decode function in encode/json. What Am I getting wrong? ID has the chance to be both a string or a nil value.

Here's me exact error incase it helps.

```
panic: EOF
```

Comment: `nil` isn't a valid JSON value.

Comment: Are you calling panic? EOF isn't a reason for a panic.

Comment: I can't just ignore the error. Removing the panic gives me a new error of: panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string

Comment: And I meant to say null. The json data comes back and gives me null not in quotes. I didn't make the system its just how it comes to me.

Comment: You need to show real code, runnable, which shows the problem.

Comment: If the json is indeed coming as `null` and not `nil` as you stated you should have no problems as the ID field is type interface{}. If you print this field you should see it represented as <nil>. I'd suggest there's something wrong with your code and it's not related to decoding the JSON. Show the code you've managed to come up with so far. No one is going to to guess what it's in your code to help you out.

Answer (score 8):

Without you showing how you're doing it, I think the best answer is to show you how to do it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    j := []byte(`{"response":"1","number":"1234","id":null}`)
    data := AutoGenerated{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}

type AutoGenerated struct {
    Response string      `json:"response"`
    Number   string      `json:"number"`
    ID       interface{} `json:"id"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON string you put here is invalid. You can find [this code sample](https://play.golang.org/p/WvHchTB4E0) for reference.

If you're going to set the *id* field to *nil*, just don't put it in the JSON string.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type AutoGenerated struct {
    Response string      `json:"response"`
    Number   string      `json:"number"`
    ID       interface{} `json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    jsonStream := `
        { "response": "1", "number": "1234" }
        { "response": "1", "number": "1234", "id": "nil" }
    `
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))
    for {
        var m AutoGenerated
        if err := decoder.Decode(&m); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(m)
    }
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
{1 1234 <nil>}
{1 1234 nil}
```

Comment: Check his comment on the question. He's receiving the JSON file as is and not generating the file. And he's also saying it comes as `null` and not nil.